# Shiny - My Redshift Database Won't Connect Once Published

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny, amazon-redshift

My Shiny application connects to my Redshift instance locally, but I get the following error when I try to run the application once I publish it to shinyapps.io

```
Warning: Error in connection_create: could not connect to server: 
Connection timed out

Is the server running on host "redshift.bi.tmmp.io" (23.23.70.97) 
and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

How would I allow connection to pass once published online?

Answer (score 0):

A time-out normally indicates that the application could not connect to the server (as opposed to the server rejecting the connection).

You should start by checking the Security Group associated with the Redshift instance to confirm that it will accept incoming connections from the application.

The best configuration is:

- A Security Group on your application instance (`App-SG`), which is associated with the application instance(s)
- A Security Group on the Redshift instance (`DB-SG`) that permits inbound Redshift (port 5439) connections from `App-SG`, which is associated with the Redshift instance

That is, the Redshift security group refers to the application security group.